# Issue writing visual basic program dealing with mathematical functions and IF logic

Tags: function, vba, boolean

First time posting on this website; mainly because I'm running into a huge issue with a question on my visual basic class that we were assigned.  The full question can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU3g3.png).

Basically, I'm running into issues where I THINK I am correctly executing the Buckling Load function as instructed, but I don't know how to get each different True or False value into the lstOut box.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnCompute_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
    Dim area As Double
    Dim length As Double
    Dim width As Double
    Dim load As Double
    Dim buckling1 As String
    Dim buckling2 As String
    Dim buckling3 As String


    length = CDbl(txtIn.Text)
    load = CDbl(txtLbs.Text)
    buckling1 = Test1(load, length, 2, area)
    buckling2 = Test1(load, length, 4, area)
    buckling3 = Test1(load, length, 6, area)


End Sub


Private Function Test1(ByVal load As Double, ByVal length As Double, ByVal width As Double, ByVal area As Double) As Boolean
    If ((0.3 * 1700000 * (length * width)) / (length / width) ^ 2) > load Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

And that's only the first part...I'm really struggling with this question.  I'm somewhat new to programming, and the concept of functions are pretty frightening.  Does anyone have any tips or advice they could give me?

Note that I'm not asking for the whole question to be completed, I'm just trying to figure out how I'm going to put all of output from the Test1, Test2, and Test3 functions into the lstOut box.  I hope I'm making at least some sense.

Comment: first thing that I see is that your function is returning a Boolean and you are assigning it to a string, I would make buckling1,2,3 Boolean varaibles, that way you can check if they are true or false to determine the output string required to your listbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the buckling variables to Boolean as Suggested by Mark Hall, or pass the words "True" or "False" instead as string so that your Buckling variables accept them
IE simply add Double Quote(s) to True (turning it to "True") and False (turning it to "False")